# Inserting data from front end to mysql db in angularjs

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs

I am trying to insert data from front end to mysql db using angularjs. **But it is not geting inserted to the db even though there are no error messages**. Following is the code that I use.

**index.html**

```
<html ng-app="demoApp">
   <head>
        <title> AngularJS Sample</title>
        <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container" ng-view>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
    demoApp.config( function ($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/',
        {
            controller: 'SimpleController',
            templateUrl: 'Partials/view1.html'
        })
        .when('/view2',
        {
            controller: 'SimpleController',
            templateUrl: 'Partials/view2.html'
        })
        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
    });
    demoApp.controller('SimpleController',function ($scope,$http){
    $http.post('server/view.php').success(function(data){
        $scope.friends = data;
    });;
    $scope.addNewFriend = function(add){
        var data = {
            fname:$scope.newFriend.fname,
            lname:$scope.newFriend.lname
        }
        $http.post("server/insert.php",data).success(function(data, status, headers, config){
            console.log("inserted Successfully");
        });
        $scope.friends.push(data);
        $scope.newFriend = {
            fname:"",
            lname:""
        };
    };   
});
```

**View1.html**

```
<div class="container" style="margin:0px 100px 0px 500px;">
    Name:<input type="text" ng-model="filter.name">
    <br/>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:filter.name | orderBy:'fname'">{{friend.fname}} {{friend.lname}}</li>
    </ul>
    <br/>
    <fieldset style="width:200px;">
        <legend>Add Friend</legend>
        <form name="addcustomer" method="POST">
            First Name:<input type="text" ng-model="newFriend.fname" name="firstname"/>
            <br/>
            Last Name :<input type="text" ng-model="newFriend.lname" name="lastname"/>
            <br/>
            <button data-ng-click="addNewFriend()" name="add">Add Friend</button>
        </form>
    </fieldset>
    <a href="#/view2" style="margin:auto;">Next</a>
</div>
```

and following is my php file

**insert.php**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['add']))
    {
        $firsname=$_POST['firstname'];
        $laname = $_POST['lastname'];
        mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()); 
        mysql_select_db("angularjs") or die(mysql_error()); 
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO friends (fname,lname) VALUES ('$firsname', '$laname')"); 
        Print "Your information has been successfully added to the database."; 
    }
?>
```

I know I am doing something stupid here. I have just started to learn angularjs today. 
when i try the php code with plain html to insert into db it works perfectly.I am not getting what I am doing wrong here. Hope someone will help me out here

Comment: If the php is working without the angular, then we can discount it as the cause, but you should be using mysqli_* or PDO rather than the mysql_* functions. Using the Chrome developer tool, or similar, can you see the XHR doing the POST to your script? Does it have a value for "add"? I can't see where you are setting the post "add" value, but I am unfamiliar with angular. More information on why not to use mysql_* can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: do you get a callback or at least some response code for request code ?

Comment: Definitely looks like you are not sending a _POST["add"] value, and so not entering the if.

Comment: But the same code is working perfectly in regular php... @boodle

Comment: i am not geting the response...if i am right I should get "Your information has been successfully added to the database." as response . But not geting it when done with angularjs. But i gets the response in regular php @VinodLouis

Comment: i'm asking about console are you sure the call is made to server ?

Comment: I can see insert.php in the network and it is not showing any error...@VinodLouis

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your script for inserting the data is wrong. Replace it with the following

```
$http.post("server/insert.php",{'fstname': $scope.newFriend.fname, 'lstname': $scope.newFriend.lname})
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
            console.log("inserted Successfully");
        });
```

and also change the php as follows.

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$fstname = mysql_real_escape_string($data->fstname);
$lstname = mysql_real_escape_string($data->lstname);
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("angularjs") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_query("INSERT INTO friends (fname,lname) VALUES ('$fstname', '$lstname')"); 
Print "Your information has been successfully added to the database.";
```

This worked for me when I tried with your code.